# Getting the actual (absolute) execution time of the last query in PHP (excluding network latency etc)

Tags: php, mysql, function, execution-time

I want to get the actual Mysql query execution times while they run in my project so running PHP `microtime()` before and after and subtracting won't work.

When we run a query in command line, the result displays the timing information something like this:-

```
xxx rows affected in YY sec
```

How to get the same time information using PHP. I searched in [PHP's Mysql functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php) in other SO question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473029/find-time-to-execute-mysql-query-via-php),and [here](http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/showthread.php?t=2100256) but did not get anything similar. Is there no such PHP function like `mysql_error()`, `mysql_affected_rows()` which return other important information? If not why is it not there? Any reasoning?

Someone says -

> I think that best way to get execution
>   time is to use some program execution
>   functions like exec() or system().

Does anybody have a working PHP code which returns the actual execution time?

Comment: Its impossible for PHP to measure the execution tie of the query without any contribution from parsing php code / network latency - only the DBMS can do this (but you can retrieve the value from the DBMS using PHP). However in most cases a more sensible approach is to get mysql to log it directly.

Comment: btw is your question answered?

Comment: @ITroubs, thanks for the solution, I will check run this and let you know

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try this:

```
<?php

$host='localhost';
$username='testing';
$password='testing';
$dbname='test';

$DBC = new mysqli($host,$username,$password,$dbname);

$DBC->query('set profiling=1');
$DBC->query('SELECT * FROM abc');
if ($result = $DBC->query("SHOW profiles", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)) {


    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        var_dump($row);
    }
    $result->close();
}
if ($result = $DBC->query("show profile for query 1", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)) {


    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        var_dump($row);
    }
    $result->close();
}
$DBC->query('set profiling=0');

?>
```

the first `if` statement gives you the overall execution time for your query like this:

```
array(3) { [0]=>  string(1) "1" [1]=>  string(10) "0.00024300" [2]=>  string(17) "SELECT * FROM abc" }
```

the second `if` statement gives you the detaild execution times of your query.
The results should be exact since you are using the mysql internal profiler.

Comment: i juste used mysqli because i am used to it. you also can use the normal mysql functions for this task