# How to get Mysql execute messager from php code?

Tags: php, mysql

How to i get messager from mysql query ?

Ex :

```
$results = $this->query("SELECT * FROM tbl.admin");

if($results){
    echo 'Affected rows: 0 , 6 total results , Time: 0.001s';
}else{
    echo $mysql_error;
}
```

so when i use update,delete query when execute success i will get messager like

"1 row affected."

how can i do ?

Thanks and Regards

Comment: If it's just affected rows.. use `$results->affected_rows` property although, for script execution time at Database level (not at `PHP` level) is another matter..

Comment: Ah hah! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031934/getting-the-actual-absolute-execution-time-of-the-last-query-in-php-excluding

Comment: but query get from $_POST['query'] so i need the messager is auto respone from query , like phpmyadmin !!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this

```
if (!is_bool($results)) {
    $num_rows= mysql_num_rows($results);
    echo "Number of rows returned $num_rows";
} else {
    echo "No rows returned.";
}
```

Hope that helps.